# Regex: How to require that a certain character be followed only by one or more digits

Tags: regex, typescript

Here's my regex:

```
^[0-9\(\)\*\+\/\-\sd]*$
```

It matches things like: '2d6', '(3d6) + 3', etc.

But it also matches: '3d'

I want any 'd' to always be **followed** by 1 or more digits.

Comment: More, the regex will match strings like `)))((((++++`. I doubt your regex makes much sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't really care about that example - I have another check that will take care of that. I really just want to require 1 or more digits after any d character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you really want to match some arbitrary string of a limited set of characters (eg. `(2511****d4+++(`) but also ensure that the `d` is followed by a number, then you can split the regex into two alternatives `(…|…)`:

   ```
   ^([\d\(\)\*\+\/\-\s]|d\d+)*$
     ------------------ ----
              |           |
     single characters   dN
   ```
2. But if you want to match a more specific pattern, such as `number` `d` `number` optionally parenthesized, optionally followed by `operator` `number`, then you'll need a better tailored regex. For example:

   ```
   ^(\d+d\d+|\( *\d+d\d+ *\))( *[\+\-\*\/] *\d+)?$
     ------- ---------------    ----------  ---
        |           |                |       |
       NdN       ( NdN )          operator   N
   ```
3. On the third hand, if your string is an arbitrary mathematical expression, then you'll *probably* need something like a [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) to handle nested expressions.

Comment: Your first example works for me in a tester, just not so far in my Typescript code, which is weird. So, 3d6 means roll 3 six-sided dice and add the total together. So I have a regex that grabs those out of a formula and replaces them with the rolled result. I pass that into a math expression validator, since at that point it's just numbers, paraens, and operators. If that fails, I catch that error. And while 'd6' I handle as 1d6, I can't do anything with '3d'.

Comment: Hey, I actually got it to work! I was using it in two different places, and didn't update both with your version. I'm sorry I can't upvote your answer since I don't have the rep. Thanks again!